# Binary file was removed from activity of iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm confused that my iOS binary file was automatically removed from activity of iTunesConnect.

I confirmed that the binary file was uploaded as shown in the image. And I tried twice though..
Is this iTunesConnect bug or Should I fix something in my code?

Does anyone have suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding missing privacy-sensitive key data usage in apps "Info.plist" the problem can be fixed.

1. Check and add the missing keys in your Info.plist file. Refer the link https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html for more info.
2. Some keys might be used by the 3rd party pods included in your application. Find them and include in your Info.plist file.(You can get them easily from App Store email sent to you)
3. Keys Examples similar to which you will need to add: NSCalendarsUsageDescription,NSContactsUsageDescription, NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription, NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription etc.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I found the problem in Info.plist. Thank you